# CodeIgniter and showing images / uploading images

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I am working on a gallery which is supposed to say "Please upload an image" if there are no images in the folder, but next to that also show the image uploaded but these things arent working correctly.

no errors are being shown.

Uploading images and changing them into thumbnails work and they go in the correct folder, but pulling them out is a different story, I have checked these values and they go to the correct destination:

```
    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images');
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url() . 'images/';
```

and this is my autoload:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'file');
```

this is the view where I am suspecting $data is coming out empty?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<title>Gallery</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="gallery">
    <?php if (isset($data) && count($data)) : ;?>


        <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
            <div class="thumb">
                <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['thumb_url']; ?>" />
                </div>
        <?php endforeach; else: ?>

        <div id="blank_gallery">Please upload an image</div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<div id="upload">

<?php

echo form_open_multipart('gallery');
echo form_upload('userfile');
echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');
echo form_close();
?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is my controller:

```
<?php
class Gallery extends CI_Controller
{
function index()
{
    $this->load->model('Gallery_model');
    if($this->input->post('upload'))
    {
        //handle upload
        $this->Gallery_model->do_upload();
    }

    $data['images'] = $this->Gallery_model->get_images();

    $this->load->view('gallery', $data);
}


}


?>
```

this is the model:

```
<?php
class Gallery_model extends CI_Model{

var $gallery_path;
var $gallery_path_url;

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images');
    $this->gallery_path_url = base_url() . 'images/';
}

function do_upload()
{

    //handle userfile
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
        'upload_path' => $this->gallery_path,
        'max_size' => 2000
    );


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()) 
    {
        die($this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    $image_data = $this->upload->data();


    $config = array(
        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
        'new_image' => $this->gallery_path . '/thumbs',
        'maintain_ratio' => true,
        'width' => 150,
        'height' => 100
    );

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    $this->image_lib->resize();
        if(!$this->image_lib->resize()) 
        {
            die($this->image_lib->display_errors());
        }
}

function get_images(){
    $files = scandir($this->gallery_path);
    $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));

    $images = array();

    foreach ($files as $file){
        $images[] = array(
            'url' => $this->gallery_path_url . $file,
            'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url . 'thumbs/' . $file,
        );

    }

}

}

?>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_images(){
    /* all the stuff you already have... */

    /* return the array! */
    return $images;
}
```

Comment: Are you telling him to move everything from the model into the function get_images? Wouldn't it be better to have these functions in the controller?

Comment: I'm not commenting on the quality of his code. I'm pointing out that the get_images() function needs to return something.